# eWay Recurring Not Taking the Recurring Payment

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, eway

I have installed and configured eWay recurring on my CiviCRM Wordpress site. The CRON jobs are running for the eWay Recurring Payments and eWay Transaction Verification jobs. Users make the initial payment OK when selecting the recurring option, however the subsequent payments are not being taken. The payment cycle is every 7 days. What should I be looking for to find out what is going wrong? I have fairly basic skills.